# Changing IP address to URL in IIS

Tags: iis, ip, url

i need some help in my school project. i need to configuring the IIS system so that user can just type in the URL in their browser rather than type in the ip address of the computer to access the data in the IIS in my computer.

Answer (score 1):

1) use Host Headers, it's like Apache ServerAlias.

You only have to create one web site, use www.yourdomain.com as your primary host header, and then add other host headers if you need.

Usign IIS, click right button under your website name and choose "Properties", go to Web Site -> Advanced Button, on "Multiple identities for this web site" press Add, then type the domain name

Example: (All Unassigned, TCP Port 80, ex.net)

Then, you have 2 choices
a) Create a CNAME, if you have a domain.
Add a CNAME entry (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx www.yourdomain.com)

b) Edit client local hosts file.
 
Add xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx www.yourdomain.com or xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx webservername
If you are using windows, edit c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.
If you are linux, edit /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

you need a DNS CNAME entry for the domain or a host file (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx webservername) entry for the system accessing the website.

if your web page IP is different from the webserver IP , then you will need to configure that bit in IIS properties and the OS NIC to listen on it (the IP) and provide an A record in DNS to point to it.

IIS isn't responsible for getting you to a particular page; the OS (host file) and/or DNS is.

someone else here will probably provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add host header entries if you are using multiple websites on IIS Server. If there is one website above solution will work you just need to Create A or CNAME Record whatever suits your environment and your users will able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this website hosted within the private school network?
Is it hosted externally with a real host?

The answer is you need DNS to do that job for you, it depends on where your website is hosted to how you can do it.

Comment: it is within the school network. so how should i do right now?

Comment: you dont, speak to the Schools IT dept. - They need to add either a CNAME or an A record pointing to the machine hosting the websites IP Address